# Check if any task in block changed?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to execute a task in Ansible only if at least one task in a specific block was changed?

So, something like this:

```yaml
- name: Tasks block
  block:
    - name: Task 1
      # ...
    - name: Task 2
      # ...
    - name: Task 3
      # ...
    - name: Task 4
      # ...
    - name: Task 5
      # ...

- name: Conditional task
  when: block_result.changed
  # ...
```

I know it is possible by registering a variable for each task in the block, then check every single one of them.
But is it possible to be done on the level of block? This is especially possible to avoid defining a lot of variables in case I have many tasks in one block.

**My main goal is to evaluate the whole changed/not changed after the whole block is finished, so that the conditional task is executed only once if needed.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case seems like the perfect fit for a [handler](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change), which are meant to run a task only **once**, even if multiple tasks are notifying them.

A typical use case, as presented in the documentation is when you are configuring a daemon and its configuration file(s), even if multiple tasks are changing some components, you want to be as less disruptive as possible and restart the daemon only once:

> Notifying the same handler multiple times will result in executing the handler only once regardless of how many tasks notify it. For example, if multiple tasks update a configuration file and notify a handler to restart Apache, Ansible only bounces Apache once to avoid unnecessary restarts.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#notifying-handlers*</sup>

If you need to trigger it at this exact location in your playbook, you will also need a [`meta: flush_handlers` task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#controlling-when-handlers-run), in order to trigger the handlers right away, and not at the end of all the tasks.

```yaml
tasks:
  - block:
      - name: Task 1
        shell: "true"
        changed_when: false

      - name: Task 2
        shell: "true"
        changed_when: true

      - name: Task 3
        shell: "true"
        changed_when: false
    notify:
      - Conditional task

  - name: Flush handlers
    meta: flush_handlers

  - debug:
      msg: I run after the handler

handlers:
  - name: Conditional task
    debug:
      msg: Running this conditional task now
```

---

Output of a play with the above code:

```
TASK [Task 1] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Task 2] *****************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Task 3] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Flush handlers] *********************************************

RUNNING HANDLER [Conditional task] ********************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Running this conditional task now

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: I run after the handler
```

Comment: Thank you! So we cannot add that `notify` on the block itself instead of adding it to every single task?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin sure you can. Answer edited.

Comment: Could you check the update please? My goal is to run the handler only once when the whole calls in the block are done. Will the approach you mentioned do that, or will it call the handler for every single task (if changed)?

Comment: Oh I see now in the docs, the handlers will be called only once, unless clreared. Right? > *Notifying the same handler multiple times will result in executing the handler only once regardless of how many tasks notify it. For example, if multiple tasks update a configuration file and notify a handler to restart Apache, Ansible only bounces Apache once to avoid unnecessary restarts.*

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin you question is answered by the definition of the handler: _Notifying the same handler multiple times will result in executing the handler only once regardless of how many tasks notify it. For example, if multiple tasks update a configuration file and notify a handler to restart Apache, Ansible only bounces Apache once to avoid unnecessary restarts._

Comment: Funny that we quoted the same text at the time. Thanks a lot!